# Turn json data into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a nested Json array that looks like :

```
{
    "areas": [
        {
            "areaCode": "1",
            "entry": [
                {
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "city": "Springfield",
                    "phonenumber": "000000000",
                    "date": "2 December 1999",
                    "available": "3 to 4PM",
                },
                {
                    "name": "Jenny Jennifer",
                    "city": "Springfield",
                    "phonenumber": "000000000",
                    "date": "10 December 2009",
                    "available": "5 to 8PM",
                },
                {
                   "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
                    "city": "New York",
                    "phonenumber": "000000000",
                    "date": "2 May 1979",
                    "available": "3 to 4PM",
                },
              ],
       }
     ],
}
```

This is actually just a snippet of the whole file (3000 + lines).

I am trying to transform this data into an html element and what I got so far :

```
var createArrayData = ( function() {
    var dataRef = '/lib/json/data.json';
    var json_obj;
    $.getJSON(dataRef, function(data){

        var json_obj = data;
        console.log(json_obj);
    })

}());
```

I manage to console log the actual data as an object but when I use a foreach to convert the data to HTMl it does not actually work...

I want to end up with something like :

```
<div>
    <h1>data.areaCode</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>name</p>
            <p>city</p>
            <p>phonenumber</p>
            <p>date</p>
            <p>available</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

of course it has to be printed for each item in the array

Comment: Have you looked into angularJS?  It's a great framework for projects like this

Comment: unfortunately can not use any framework as its an existing project

Comment: What do you mean by convert data to html?

Comment: What do you mean you want to transform it into HTML? ? do you want a div to be filled with the data? Input form to be created??

Comment: "when I use a foreach to convert the data to HTMl it does not actually work" — You forgot to include your code that tries to do that. We can't tell you what the problem is without seeing it.

Comment: You code example shows absolutely nothing having to do with populating the data into DOM.  Can you show what you have tried and more clearly explain what problem you are having in doing this?

Comment: see edit please , sorry English is not my first language

Comment: `var json_obj = data;`
`console.log(typeof(json_obj)); // does it log "string" or "object"?`

I think your problem is that your json_obj might be a string, instead of an object, and you have to parse it to get a json object.

Comment: @PedroBaracho — There is no way that `getJSON` would populate `data` with a string. (Well, unless the JSON data consisted solely of a string literal, which the quoted JSON clearly isn't)

Comment: @greatTeacherOnizuka — You still haven't shown us your attempt to convert the data to HTML.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It works to output your correctly formatted json data.

Comment: After my last update, I saw that I forgot to display areaCode. So I now have that added as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
function getHTML(json) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i in json.areas) {
    var area = json.areas[i];
    result += "<div>";
    result += "<h1>" + area.areaCode + "</h1>";
    result += "<ul>";
    for (var j in area.entry) {
      var entry = area.entry[j];
      result += "<li>";
      result += "<p>" + entry.name + "</p>";
      result += "<p>" + entry.city + "</p>";
      result += "<p>" + entry.phonenumber + "</p>";
      result += "<p>" + entry.date + "</p>";
      result += "<p>" + entry.available + "</p>";
      result += "</li>"
    }
    result += "</ul>";
    result += "</div>";
  }
  return result;
}

var createArrayData = ( function() {
    var dataRef = '/lib/json/data.json';
    var json_obj;
    $.getJSON(dataRef, function(data){

        var json_obj = data;
        $('.output').html(getHTML(json_obj));
    })

}());
```

Comment: There were some reference errors on the original post. I just edited to fix it.

Comment: thanks you are a star!

Answer (score 0):

Hi heres an example of how to iterate through your JSON object with simple For loops.. Just uncomment the lines I have commented in document ready.

**[JSFiddle of it in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/tjxaoxnn/)**

```
function getHTML(json) {
    var result = "";
    for (i = 0; i < json.areas.length; i++) {
        result += "<div>";
        result += "<h1>" + json.areas[i].areaCode + "</h1>";
        result += "<ul>";
        for (j = 0; j < json.areas[i].entry.length; j++) {
            var e = json.areas[i].entry[j];
            result += "<li>";
            result += "<p>" + e.name + "</p>";
            result += "<p>" + e.city + "</p>";
            result += "<p>" + e.phonenumber + "</p>";
            result += "<p>" + e.date + "</p>";
            result += "<p>" + e.available + "</p>";
            result += "</li>"
        }
        result += "</ul>";
        result += "</div>";
    }
    return result;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var dataRef = '/lib/json/data.json';
    //$.getJSON(dataRef, function (data) {
        $('.result').html(getHTML(JSON2));//change JSON2 to data;
    //}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is use $.ajax({}); I've modified my solution to use .forEach, and output your json data. Your json data in the original post had some errors. All the commas had to be removed. Take the below and run it and your data will be output as you intend. I also just updated to show areaCode, which I forgot to show before.

Now including a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37u1ywvz/1/

Updating my code because the poster must not like that I didn't use their HTML structure.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'jsondata.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            listData(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#dataoutput').html('Error: Data not available.');
        }
    });

});

function listData(str){

    str.areas.forEach(function(area) {
        area.entry.forEach(function(element) {

            $('#dataoutput').append(
                '<div>' + 
                    '<h1>Area Code: ' + area.areaCode + '</h1>' + 
                    '<ul>' + 
                        '<li>' + 
                            '<p>Name: ' + element.name + '</p>' + 
                            '<p>City: ' + element.city + '</p>' + 
                            '<p>Phone Number: ' + element.phonenumber + '</p>' + 
                            '<p>Date: ' + element.date + '</p>' + 
                            '<p>Available: ' + element.available + '</p>' +
                        '</li>' + 
                    '</ul>' + 
                '</div>'
            );
        });
    });
```

Properly formatted JSON data, fixing errors in original post:

```
{
    "areas": [
        {
            "areaCode": "1",
            "entry": [
                {
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "city": "Springfield",
                    "phonenumber": "000000000",
                    "date": "2 December 1999",
                    "available": "3 to 4PM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Jenny Jennifer",
                    "city": "Springfield",
                    "phonenumber": "000000000",
                    "date": "10 December 2009",
                    "available": "5 to 8PM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
                    "city": "New York",
                    "phonenumber": "000000000",
                    "date": "2 May 1979",
                    "available": "3 to 4PM"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```